# Git pending changes file preview in Visual Studio 2013 RC

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

How do I get a "diff preview" option inside Visual Studio 2013 RC when working with Git?  Most other source control extensions have this (including [Git Source Control Provider](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c), which I used in VS2012), where the list of uncommitted changes are listed to the left, and a color-coded diff of the selected file is shown on the right.

I can get diffs for individual files by looking in Team Explorer, Changes, right-clicking on an individual file, then selecting Compare with unmodified.  But I have to do this for each file I want to see the current diff for, which is much more cumbersome than the "split" view I'm used to.

There are two possible options.  The first is I don't know where to look.  The second is it's just not available, and I'm stuck using an external tool like gitk.

For clarity, the screenshot below is the exact feature that I'm referring to in the Git Source Control Provider extension for Visual Studio 2012.

[image: Git Source Control Provider screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using this package:  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c  (and it looks like you are...)

1) Download a fresh copy of the .vsix file.
2) Rename it to .zip.
3) Extract all.
4) Edit the `extension.vsixmanifest` file, copying the entire `<VisualStudio Version="11.0">` element and changing the 11 to 12.
5) Repackage everything back in to the original .zip.
6) Rename the .zip to .vsix, double-click the .vsix and you should be able to install into VS2013.

HTH --