# Visual Studio 2013 Configure Remote Git Repo

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, git-remote

I'm completely new to git, but I'm trying to learn. I followed [this guide](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) 
and I got it working on a network share. I used git bash. I've found how to do a lot of it with the Visual Studio GUI, which is what I would prefer rather than having to go back and forth to the command line (I'm coming from Visual Source Safe where you just do pending checkins, checkin, and you're done).

The only command I couldn't find was:

`git remote add origin <server>`

How do I do that for a UNC share in Visual Studio 2013, in the GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge `Visual Studio Tools for Git` (VS Git Support) does not yet support managing remotes, unfortunately. I believe the team at MSFT responsible for VS Git features has it backlogged, but it's low priority.

See the comments on [SO#21469233](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469233/error-on-creating-new-git-project-in-visual-studio-2013/21740155#21740155) re: [Edward Thomson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729881/edward-thomson).

Comment: So, to be clear, currently the only method of configuring remotes is via command-line (or other tool.)

Comment: I didn't say it was low priority, only that I didn't know what the priority was!  :)  This functionality landed in VS 2015.

Comment: So what's my workflow then? I'm used to making a new project in VS2010, then "Add to Source Control" and give it a folder in VSS. What's the workflow here?

Comment: @John You'll have to run `git remote add origin <server>` from the command-line.