# Visual Studio 2013 Plugin for BitBucket

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, bitbucket

We are using a BitBucket for our .NET project (Visual Studio 2013)

At the moment I'm using below:
1. Source Tree
2. Git Source Provider Extension.

Given that I come from TFS background, I would like to use Visual Studio to manage source control (checkout/checkin/merge/rollback/history/compare etc.)

Could someone please help me if there are any plugin for Bit Bucket which tightly integrates with Visual Studio?

I also looked at thread below:

[Visual Studio 2013 and BitBucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836351/visual-studio-2013-and-bitbucket)

However, I could not find a way to specify remote repository. All I can see it "Sign Up" for visual studio GIT.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're looking at?  You should be able to clone from any http/https remote in Team Explorer.

Comment: Hmm.  Can you post a screenshot of the About Microsoft Visual Studio dialog?  (From Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio)

Answer (score 1):

Not BitBucket specific but try using "Git Extensions" it has a nice graphic interface and Visual Studio toolbar to integrate with visual studio. It uses it's own UI for the operations, not visual studio's but I've found it to be the best tool for interfacing with git.
You can set BitBucket as a remote repository using https or ssh (integrates with PUTTY or Open SSH).

The git extensions install will also (optionally) install git for you.

[Git extensions website](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) also available via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/gitextensions)

Comment: Yep, this is what I'm using. The problem is this doesn't seem to support Git Sub Modules and also everytime I push or pull the tool asks for Git password.

Comment: You can solve the git password problem: if it is https then there should be a checkbox for saving the password in window's password vault. For ssh you may need to leave the private key unprotected, but I think putty will just ask once. Regarding sub-modules, I've never used them but seems Git-Extensions does support them (http://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/submodules.html)